# autobreak not working if left and right delimeter breaks

Tags: line-breaking

My code follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,autobreak}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{autobreak}
a+b=c\left(\sum
+\prod\right)
\end{autobreak}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

if I remove the `linebreak` after `sum` then it works nice. Is this any possible to make it work even if the `left and right delimeter` breaks.

Comment: `\left`... `\right` makes an unbreakable box, use `\bigl(`....`\bigr)`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But bigl and bigr size is fixed one, but I need to raise the bracket size based on the text

Comment: well give up automatic breaking (although in most cases you will get better spacing by not using `\left`, `\right`)

Comment: Or, you could measure the height of the formula beforehand, and then insert `\vphantom`s of that height in both halves of the formula.  For an example of this technique, see the manual of the `mathtools` package, at the end of subsection 3.6 (p. 29–30, where it says “Feature provided by Sebastien Gouezel 2014/05/14”).

Comment: @GuM But then `autobreak` will not work.