# autobreak formula but doesn't work

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, line-breaking, page-breaking

I have a long formula , I use autobreak as follows,but it doesn't work

```
\begin{align}
\begin{autobreak}
{E_{{S_{t + 1}}}}\left[ {\left. {E\left[ {\left. {{G_{t + 1}}} \right|{S_t},{S_{t + 1}}} \right]} \right|{S_{t + 1}}} \right] = {E_{{S_{t + 1}}}}\left[ {\left. {E\left[ {\left. {{G_{t + 1}}} \right|{S_{t + 1}}} \right]} \right|{S_{t + 1}}} \right] = \sum\limits_{{S_{t + 1}}} {P\left( {\left. {{S_{t + 1}}} \right|{S_t}} \right)V\left( {{S_{t + 1}}} \right)} 
\end{autobreak}
\end{align}
```

It still overflows the page,how to let long formula breakline?

Is there some useful and general template how to insert formula into document?That solve these problems?

Comment: Duplicate of [autobreak not working if left and right delimeter breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423279/autobreak-not-working-if-left-and-right-delimeter-breaks) but that also has no answer.

Comment: @Henri Menke , maybe my problem is not the same as this,since I don't have \left ,\right. And I have an additional question,a "perfect"  template for equation.

Comment: Ctrl+F "`\left`": 11 matches. ???

Comment: Oh...you are right. my ignorant eye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `multline` or `align`, take your pick.

However you should drop *all* `\left` and `\right` here, and also the useless braces. For the outer brackets, `\bigl[` and `\bigr]` suffice.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
E_{S_{t + 1}}\bigl[E[G_{t + 1}\mid S_t,S_{t + 1}] \mid S_{t + 1}\bigr] \\
=E_{S_{t + 1}}\bigl[E[G_{t + 1}\mid S_{t + 1}] \mid S_{t + 1}\bigr] =
\sum_{S_{t + 1}} P(S_{t + 1}\mid S_t) V(S_{t + 1})
\end{multline}

\begin{align}
E_{S_{t + 1}}\bigl[E[G_{t + 1}\mid S_t,S_{t + 1}] \mid S_{t + 1}\bigr]
&=E_{S_{t + 1}}\bigl[E[G_{t + 1}\mid S_{t + 1}] \mid S_{t + 1}\bigr] \notag \\
&=\sum_{S_{t + 1}} P(S_{t + 1}\mid S_t) V(S_{t + 1})
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility is `split`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
E_{S_{t + 1}}\bigl[E[G_{t + 1}\mid S_t,S_{t + 1}] \mid S_{t + 1}\bigr]
  &=E_{S_{t + 1}}\bigl[E[G_{t + 1}\mid S_{t + 1}] \mid S_{t + 1}\bigr] \\
  &=\sum_{S_{t + 1}} P(S_{t + 1}\mid S_t) V(S_{t + 1})
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use autobreqak environment. With manual breaking of your equation (using `split` environment and `\MoveEqLeft` function from `amsmath` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{autobreak}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \MoveEqLeft
E_{S_{t + 1}} \bigl[E [G_{t + 1} \big| S_t, S_{t + 1}] \big| S_{t + 1} \bigr]       \\
    & = E_{S_{t + 1}}\bigl[E [ G_{t + 1} \big| S_{t + 1} ] \big| S_{t + 1} \bigr]
      = \sum_{S_{t + 1}} P\bigl(S_{t + 1} \big| S_t \bigr) V(S_{t + 1})
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
one more solution, using  `multlined` from the package  `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}[0.8\linewidth]
E_{S_{t + 1}} \bigl[E [G_{t + 1} \big| S_t, S_{t + 1}] \big| S_{t + 1} \bigr]       \\
     = E_{S_{t + 1}}\bigl[E [ G_{t + 1} \big| S_{t + 1} ] \big| S_{t + 1} \bigr]
     = \sum_{S_{t + 1}}P\bigl(S_{t + 1} \big| S_t \bigr) V(S_{t + 1})
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Comment: It seems quite nice ,thx